# How to configure amazon cloudfront to block some S3 bucket files access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

On S3 we have all files as private. Users can't load any file through S3 link. But they are all public through cloudfront link.

How can i restrict access to ./restricted.txt? (only users who use signed URL link can see that file through cloudfront link), ./not_restricted.txt must be public the same time.

How i did that.

I have created /public & /private folders on s3, separated my private/public files, created cloudfront origin that point to /public. So all my S3 files which are in /public folder are public and i can load them using link without public prefix /img1.jpg istead /public/img1.jpg, because cloudfront thinks about /public as a root folder.

Now all my files that are in /private or any other place above /public folder are private through either S3 and cloudfront links.

But i don't know how to create signed URL for /private/restricted.txt file that will have cloudfront path. I can create signed url which use S3 path, but i need to have cloudfront link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Within CloudFront there is the concept of "Cache Behaviours". Based on URL paths these allow you to modify caching behaviour, including the requirement to use Signed URL/Cookies.

If I understand it you want to:

- Maintain your private S3 bucket
- Maintain some public paths through CloudFront (/public)
- Have a private path through CloudFront (/private)

This could be done by simply adding a new Cache Behaviour within your CloudFront distribution and setting `Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies)` to Yes. For instance:

[image: CloudFront Cache Policy]

So to reiterate, the easiest way to achieve this would be

- Use OAI between S3 and CloudFront
- Have a single CloudFront distribution pointing to your S3 bucket (root, rather than /public)
- Create a new cache behaviour which enables signed URLs for /private

If this doesn't answer your question, for instance if you need to maintain paths and can't use /public and /private in the URL schema itself, let me know with a comment and I can try to elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried to do this?

Amazon support answer is "it's impossible". I have tried to add one more behavior, but private file stays visible, even when Restrict Access (only signed urls cookies) option is enabled. 

I guess this happen because you can't change default behavior entry point and it's *. So it serve private files regardless the second behavior. Thanks. You understand clearly what i want to achieve.

Comment: @Rantiev - Let me try this and confirm. I could well be wrong! :) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Rantiev Yep - just tested this now and it works on my test CF distribution. Example Behaviours: http://cf.alexjs.im/tmp/cf-private.png -- and then http://cf-beta.alexjs.im/private http://cf-beta.alexjs.im/public http://cf-beta.alexjs.im/ -- all look to work

Comment: Is that file link? http://cf-beta.alexjs.im/private or just empty folder?
Could you provide 2 links which has the same path except for /public /private part
I mean http://cf-beta.alexjs.im/private/private.png http://cf-beta.alexjs.im/public/public.png

cf-beta - is this cloudfront distributive path or your S3 bucket name?

Comment: I made it work on my setup. So I created 2 behaviors:
1. for /private when signing in ON
2. for * (default) when signing is OFF